# What is using mobile data while connected to wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

Since a recent Android (6.01) update was pushed to my non-rooted Samsung G5 SM-G900I, while connected to wifi, the notification area shows quick 4G connection is made every three seconds (like a heart beat).

How can I find out what is responsible for this activity?

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung Galaxy devices running KitKat and above, there is an option called ***Smart network switch***, which if it enabled makes your device connected to a mobile network automatically when the Wifi connection is unstable.

You can disable it on Settings > Wifi> More > Smart network switch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that mode was already set. Unusually, frequency wise, I had a subsequent update made available to my phone, and I have not see the problem recur, so hopefully it was just a poor quality software update.